# Why does my SSIS package not pull all the data from a specific table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

**Situation**: I have created an SSIS package that has a OLE DB Source that is an Oracle Database and an OLE DB destination of SQL Server. I use [Oracle Provider for OLE DB] connection.

**Problem**: when I execute the package it will run short and only return 220,000 out of 4 million records. The package runs with no errors and no warnings. Just successfully completes but will not go past 220,000 records. I found one similar problem on this site however it pointed to a date format issue and this table has no date data types in its structure.

Troubleshooting so far:

1. I extracted the table as a flat file and ran the package to the same destination table, this runs fine. All 4 million records will load from flat file to destination ok.
2. I have tried running the package as a fast load and a normal - no change
3. I have tried different buffer combinations and Auto Adjust Buffer Size - no change
4. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, VS, Oracle 12c, SSDT - No change
5. I thought maybe it could be memory or size issue, no luck, I load many other tables that are larger in size memory wise.

Environment Specs:

- VS V 15.9.14
- Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12.2.0.1.0
- SSDT 15.1.61906.3120
- SSIS 15.0.1301.433
- SQL Server 2016 13.0.4 - SP1

Has anyone dealt with something like this what are somethings I could try or look into?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to try with different provider and see if the issue is repeating. you can try with ORACLE instant client or ORACLE .NET provider or Oracle client

Comment: Try capturing the query that is being submitted https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database

Comment: @VenkataramanR Thank you for the suggestion I am still pretty new to this so forgive me for now understanding fully. The only provider I can get to successfully connect for me in SSIS is the OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 provider. Also I forgot to mention that I have very limited permissions to the oracle database. Thanks again for the response.